# Removing integer only strings from nested Lists

Tags: python, list, function, syntax, integer

I have lists that I am trying to remove integer only data from. I want to keep any strings that have $, +, or -, in them.

```
string = (",A', B', C', +145', $50', Split', D', E', F', 1', 2000', -678', $10', Split', H', I', J', 3', 4', 50', +132', $45', Split'").replace("'", '')

ls_of_lists = [x.split(",") for x in string.split('Split')]

# What I want my out put to be:

desired_ls_of_ls = [
    ["A", "B", "C", "+145", "$50"],
    ["D", "E", "F", "-678", "$10"],
    ["H", "I", "J", "+132","$45"]
]
```

I've tried so many things and I bet it's something easy I'm missing/overlooking. On all modified int_filters(see below) I tried search, .contains, and other methods I could think of and looking around the web hasn't helped me either. I've also tried swapping yield and return.

Below is my work:

```
def int_filter_0( someList ):
    for v in someList:
        try:
            int(v)
            continue # Skip these
        except ValueError:
            yield v # Keep these


def int_filter_1(some_list):
    for v in some_list:
        if v.find("\\+"):
            yield v  # Keep these
        if v.find("\\-"):
            yield v  # Keep these
        else:
            try:
                int(v)
                continue # Skip these
            except ValueError:
                yield v # Keep these

def int_filter_2(some_list):
    for v in some_list:
        if v.contains("\\+"):
            yield v  # Keep these
        if v.contains("\\-"):
            yield v  # Keep these
        else:
            try:
                int(v)
                continue # Skip these
            except ValueError:
                yield v # Keep these


def int_filter_3( someList ):
    for v in someList:
        try:
            if v.find("\\+"):
                continue
            if v.find("\\-"):
                continue
            int(v)
            continue # Skip these
        except ValueError:
            yield v # Keep these



test_0 = [list(int_filter_0(item)) for item in ls_of_lists]

test_1 = [list(int_filter_1(item)) for item in ls_of_lists]

test_2 = [list(int_filter_2(item)) for item in ls_of_lists]

test_3 = [list(int_filter_3(item)) for item in ls_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
string = (",A', B', C', +145', $50', Split', D', E', F', 1', 2000', -678', $10', Split', H', I', J', 3', 4', 50', +132', $45', Split'")
string = string.replace("'", '').replace(' ', '') # clean ' and spaces
ls_of_lists = [x.split(",") for x in string.split('Split')]

ls_of_lists = [[c for c in ls if (not c.isdigit() and c)] for ls in ls_of_lists] # Clean the numbers and empty strings
ls_of_lists = [ls for ls in ls_of_lists if ls]  # Clean empty lists
for l in ls_of_lists:
    print(l)

# Output:
# ['A', 'B', 'C', '+145', '$50']
# ['D', 'E', 'F', '-678', '$10']
# ['H', 'I', 'J', '+132', '$45']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a efficient method using a regex and a generator:

```
import re
def split(s):
    l = []
    for x in re.split(',\s*', s):
        if x.isdigit() or not x:
            continue
        elif x == 'Split':
            yield l
            l = []
        else:
            l.append(x)
   # if l:
   #     yield l

out = list(split(string))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', '+145', '$50'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F', '-678', '$10'],
 ['H', 'I', 'J', '+132', '$45']]
```

*NB. If you want to get the values even if there is no terminal "Split", uncomment the last two lines.*

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. ON the If v.find it needs to be more direct(Not include the \)and include the !=

```
def int_filter_1(some_list):
    for v in some_list:
        if v.find("+") != -1:
            yield v  # Keep these
        if v.find("-")!= -1:
            yield v  # Keep these
        else:
            try:
                int(v)
                continue # Skip these
            except ValueError:
                yield v # Keep these
```

This gives me the corrected results

Comment: `v.find("+") != -1` is more commonly written as `"+" in v`

Comment: Where do you remove all the `'` characters after each item in the list.

Comment: .replace("'", '') is on the end of the string = (etc,etc,etc)